# PHP: Leftover text in Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

Trying to write a script where a user inputs [link](http://www.example.com) and gets back a hyperlink named "link" with "http://www.example.com" as the href.  Here's my code:

```
if(preg_match("/\[[a-zA-Z0-9]*\]([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/", $input))
{
    $input = preg_replace("/\[([a-zA-Z0-0-9]*)\](([a-zA-Z0-9]*))/", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $input);
}
```

What I keep getting back is `[link](http://www.example.com)(http://www.example.com)`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're processing Markdown, there are already tools to do that for you, such as http://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually rolling my own code to learn regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to escape the literal parentheses (therefore the `(([a-zA-Z0-9]*))` part simply matched the empty string).

Also, you'll need to allow at least slashes, colons and dots if you want to match links:

```
$input = preg_replace("%\[([A-Z0-9]*)\]\(([A-Z0-9/:.]*)\)%i", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $input);
```

or possibly

```
$input = preg_replace("%\[([A-Z0-9]*)\]\((https?://[A-Z0-9/.]*)\)%i", "<a href='$2'>$1</a>", $input);
```